# Need a confidence level or statistical significance formula for A/B testing price

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multivariate-analysis, multiple-comparisons, ab-test

I need a formula to determine a confidence level for which **Price** maximizes profit.

I will know total page views, conversions(purchases), the tested prices of the unit, and the cost of each unit.

I am building an A/B tester for testing different prices for a given product.  The goal being to determine the price that maximizes profit.  The summary table looks like this, I just need a formula for confidence.

(assume Cost per item = $5 )

```
Price | PageViews | Number of Purchases | Profit  
  25       1000              30            $600    
  50       1000              12            $540  
  70       1000               8            $520

                   **Best Price: $25**
             **84% Confidence (for example)**
```

*note profit = ( (price - cost) X Number of Purchases )

What I know:
Intuitively I understand the the lower the conversion rate the lower the greater the needed sample size, since one additional marginal unit will have greater effect on things.

I do not have a statistics background, I have a programming background so while any solution with Greek symbols are welcome (I've noticed there are conventions), please include a key so I know what each greek letter represents.  Or else, your response will quite literally "look like Greek to me."